# Ajax render not working on SelectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a JSF form and on which I have a selectBooleanCheckbox. If the value of the checkbox is true I want to display the combo box next to it. But somehow it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
      <h:outputText value="Condition"/>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="provisioningTargetCollector" 
                           value="#{targetSource.provisioningTargetCollector}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
                           <f:ajax  render="targetCollectorsGroup" />
                           </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

      <h:outputText value="Provisioning Target Collector"/>
      <h:panelGroup id="targetCollectorsGroup">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="targetCollectors">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="collector"
                           value="#{targetSource.selectedTargetCollector}"
                           rendered="#{empty targetSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_provisioning_target_collector}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{targetSource.targetCollectors}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="fixedTargetCollector" value="#{empty targetSource.selectedTargetCollector ? 'None' : targetSource.selectedTargetCollector}"
                           rendered="#{not empty targetSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="true"
                           readonly="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{empty targetSource.selectedTargetCollector ? 'None' : targetSource.selectedTargetCollector}"
                          itemLabel="#{empty targetSource.selectedTargetCollector ? msgs.none : targetSource.selectedTargetCollector}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
      </h:panelGroup>
```

Bean Class Methods:

```
private boolean _provisioningTargetCollector;

public boolean isProvisioningTargetCollector() {

    return _provisioningTargetCollector;
 }

 public void setProvisioningTargetCollector(boolean provisioningTargetCollector) {

     _provisioningTargetCollector = provisioningTargetCollector;
 }
```

Note: Copied from FireBug

This is the POST Request:

```
AJAX:EVENTS_COUNT   1
editForm    editForm
editForm:collector  
editForm:collectorType  
editForm:dsCorrelationRul...    
editForm:dsCreationRule 
editForm:dsDescription  
editForm:dsName 
editForm:id 2c90950048166abc0148177755040025
editForm:selectedTargetsF...    
editForm:type   Active Directory - Direct
javax.faces.ViewState   1920301575480395177:8510885827764100150
javax.faces.behavior.even...    click
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true
javax.faces.partial.event   click
javax.faces.partial.execu...    editForm:provisioningTargetCollector editForm:provisioningTargetCollector
javax.faces.partial.rende...    editForm:targetCollectorsGroup
javax.faces.source  editForm:provisioningTargetCollector
rfExt   null
```

Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="editForm:targetCollectorsGroup"><![CDATA[<span id="editForm:targetCollectorsGroup"><span id="editForm:targetCollectors"><select id="editForm:collector" name="editForm:collector" size="1">  <option value="">Select a Provisioning Target Collector ...</option>
    <option value="AD Test">AD Test</option>
    <option value="ADWindow">ADWindow</option>
    <option value="ADTestSth">ADTestSth</option>
</select></span></span>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[1920301575480395177:8510885827764100150]]></update><extension id="org.richfaces.extension"><render>editForm:targetCollectorsGroup</render></extension></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: can you try after adding `execute="@this"` to `f:ajax`?

Comment: @tt_emrah I tried. Still not working.

Comment: Try replace `<f:ajax  render="targetCollectorsGroup" />` with `<a4j:ajax event="click" render="targetCollectorsGroup" />`. Not related: do you really need `<h:panelGroup id="targetCollectorsGroup">`? For rendering purpose you can use `targetCollectors`.

Comment: @VasilLukach Still its not working after changing to a4j. Yeah I can do that also.

Comment: Your code is noisy. Consider removing all irrelevant tags/attributes/styles/etc. from your view that don't affect the problem under question. At first glance I'd say that your code and description are inconsistent: you want to rely on a boolean value set via a checkbox but later on render comboboxes basing on some object id presence. Why?

Comment: This code is already present like this. The "render" on combo box is to show it only while configuration. Once the form is saved it will not appear. I have to just show/hide the combo box on click of checkbox. Can I do this by using javascript instead of using ajax? I am thinking to do this that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way to achieve the functionality you desire is, literally, to rerender the combobox basing on the selection of the checkbox. That is done in a following way:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkbox}">
    <f:ajax render="group" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:panelGroup id="group">
    <h:selectOneMenu ... rendered="#{checkbox.value}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that the code doesn't need any special fields in the bean and the `UIComponent` is bound to the view.

Of course, you can do it via a bean property as well, if you need it in your model:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:ajax render="group" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:panelGroup id="group">
    <h:selectOneMenu ... rendered="#{bean.value}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Also worth noting is that this functionality can be achieved by plain JavaScript as well, by toggling the `display` attribute of an element between `none` and `block`. But be aware that you must keep the status of JSF components consistent across postbacks to secure against possible malicious attack threats.