# JSF/Primefaces Component doesn't update when trying to hide/show it from another component

Tags: user-interface, primefaces, jsf-2, show-hide

I have a Primeface xhtml page, in which one dropdown menu should be visible or not depending on wether on the value of Two radiobuttons on the page.

I have googled around on many similar questions, for example this
[Ajax render not working on SelectBooleanCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551303/ajax-render-not-working-on-selectbooleancheckbox)
but can't seem to get it to work.
My code is

```
<p:fieldset id="Settings" legend="Settings" styleClass="pFieldSet_Template" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="showCars" value="#{settingsHandler.beanSelected.showCars}">
    <p:ajax event="change" render="carSelection"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="carSelection" value="Mercedes" rendered="#{settingsHandler.beanSelected.showCars}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mercedes" itemValue="Mercedes" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Volvo" itemValue="Volvo" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fiat" itemValue="Fiat" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:fieldset>
```

and I have corresponding getters and setters in the backing bean as follows:

```
private Boolean showCars = new Boolean(false);

@Column(name = "SHOWCARS", nullable=false, columnDefinition = "bit default 'true'")
public Boolean getShowCars() { return showCars; }
public void setShowCars(Boolean value) { showCars = value; }
```

Nothing really happens with the menu though when I click the radio buttons. Similar to what the link I wrote above suggested I tried wrapping it in another component that is always rendered, but that didn't help either. Code is:

```
<p:fieldset id="Settings" legend="Settings" styleClass="pFieldSet_Template" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="showCars" value="#{settingsHandler.beanSelected.showCars}">
    <p:ajax event="change" render="group"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <h:panelGroup id="group">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="carSelection" value="Mercedes" rendered="#{settingsHandler.beanSelected.showCars}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mercedes" itemValue="Mercedes" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Volvo" itemValue="Volvo" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fiat" itemValue="Fiat" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:fieldset>
```

I've also tried some other approaches laid out in questions/answers here on Stackoverflow, but I am a bit unsure about when to use execute, update and render and whether or not to use listeners.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong attribute. In `p:ajax` you should use the `update` attribute on your second approach (the first will not work). So:

```
<p:ajax update="group"/>
```

Note that the change event is default, so I've left that one out. For more information on the `p:ajax` tag, check the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/ajaxbehavior).

For your first approach, please see [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute).